# How do I iterate a nonetype variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to edit my find_winners function where I want to print out values from number_digit and store it into mini. And from there i would use these values to see if it is divisible by f. However it keep saying that mini is a nonetype variable. I know that mini is a function but if a function has value placed in, wouldnt mini be a int function because it has been processed by the previous function? (number_digit) How do i make it such that mini is a iterable function such that the values in mini can be used for subsequent functions?

```
def number_contains(n,m): # m is the must have digit

    while n > 0 and m > 0 and 10 > m:
        if n % 10 == m:
            break
        n = n /10
        
    return (n > 0)



def number_digit(n,d): #n is the list of numbers and d is the wanted number
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        if number_contains(i,d):
            print(i)
    return 



def find_winners(f,m,n): #f is the factor out number
    count = 0
    mini = number_digit(n,m)

    for i in mini:
        if i % f ==0:
            count += 1
    return count

    print(count)
```

Comment: `print(i)` --> `yield i` and remove the `return` statement.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-37